# How to add an image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I m learing codeigniter and i want to add an image in my view page.
I am using  tag but the image is not added in the page.
So help me how i can add the image in view page of codigniter.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Blog</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h2><img src="../images/logo.png"></h2>
        <?php $this->load->view('blog/menu');
        if ($query):foreach ($query as $post): ?>
                <h4><?php echo $post->entry_name; ?> (<?php echo $post->entry_date; ?>)</h4>
                <?php echo $post->entry_body; ?>
            <?php endforeach;
        else: ?>
            <h4>No entry yet!</h4>
<?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some code please. Show us how you currently do so we can see if there is an error.

Comment: call the view page  with a controller -- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html

Comment: Look How it's built here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675135/codeigniter-best-way-to-structure-partial-views

Comment: Yes, i'm calling view page with codeigniter.

Comment: @Hatul, I know that but image is not loaded in my page.

Comment: @Kakshak try using the base_url function instead on writing the whole directory path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

store images in an images folder at the same level as the application folder . then just link to it like this using code.

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url('images/logo.png'); ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Store images in an images folder at the same level as the application folder, Then just link to it like this:

```
<img src="../../images/image1.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See, first you create a file with the name user_profile.php in the controller folder. no uppercase letters. 
To call a View page you created in the index:

```
function index()
        {
            $this->load_controller('myView');
}
```

this is an example from the link i sent you that is perfect, that shows peaces of a views and how to combine them to one code from the controller.

Please go to the codeigniter website and start learning the simple stuff. or search for codeigniter via youtube. you will find a lot!

```
Class User_Profile extends Controller
{

    function index()
    {
        $this->load_controller('Left_Nav');
        $this->load_controller('Content_Nav');
        $this->load_controller('Login_Name');
        $this->load_controller('Leaderboard', 'Board');

        $this->Left_Nav->index(array('highlight_selected_page' => 'blah'));

        $this->load('User');

        $content_data = $this->User->get_profile_details();

        $this->view->load('content', $content_data);

        $this->Login_Name->index();
        $this->Board->index();
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

image in assets

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/image.png">
```