# Error while linking header and footer from a directory inside view

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, view

I've just started a Codeigniter project and I'm facing issues in linking the header and footer files to a page inside the view's subfolder.
My directory structure is

- Application

  - Views

    - includes

      - header.php
      - footer.php
    - details

      - details-page.php
    - index.php
- System
- Assets

Linking the header and footer to `details-page.php` using `require_once` returns

> "failed to open stream: No such file or directory" error.

It works when I use `$this->load->view('includes/header');` to link the files but shows the error when using `require_once('../includes/header.php');`

Comment: what do you have in index.php? my main index.php is in root and it holds paths, etc. Maybe issue is in paths?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way using CI is to load the view in your controller.

```
 $this->load->view("file-in-views-folder");
```

However, if you want to use require_once statement then you should use CodeIgniter's built in constant `APPPATH` . Like this

```
require_once(APPPATH.'views/includes/header.php');
```

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your quick reply.. Is $this->load->view("file-in-views-folder"); works as same as require_once?  Since there are many file linking types like include,include_once and require...$this->load->view("file-in-views-folder"); is an alternate for which type in CI?

Comment: You can take look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675135/codeigniter-best-way-to-structure-partial-views and http://www.amitavroy.com/justread/content/articles/part-2-creating-partial-views-and-loading-them-inside-container-view I think this will help you.